# JSF Conditionally render errors in a row

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I would like to render the errors in a separate row of this table. However, the binding doesn't work when I use the ui:repeat as it sets all rows to the same value.

```
         <ui:repeat id="quest" value="#{questions}" var="question">
            <tr>

               <td class="col-md-2">
                     <p:selectOneRadio id="questionId" value="#{question.response}" binding="#{questionBinding}" validator="#{question.validate}" required="true" requiredMessage="You must answer the question to continue">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="Yes" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="No" />
                        <p:ajax update="error-row" />
                     </p:selectOneRadio>
              </td>


            </tr>
            <h:panelGroup id="error-row">
              <ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty facesContext.getMessageList(questionBinding.clientId)}">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><p:message for="questionId" id="msgQuestion" /></td>
                </tr>
              </ui:fragment>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </ui:repeat>
```

Comment: You have to specify the concrete `id` which will be unique according to the iterating index. You could have achieved the same thing using an iterating component like `<p:dataGrid>` instead of using a stray `<ui:repeat>` to generate `<tr>` manually.

Comment: or use a `c:foreach` in this case (but see if it has no side effects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call javascript on ajax update:

```
....
        <p:ajax update="msgQuestion" oncomplete="clearEmptyRows()" />
....
```

Using javascript function:

```
 <script>
            function clearEmptyRows() {
                $(".error-row").each(function(index) {
                    if ($(this).text().trim() == '') {
                        $(this).css("display", "none");
                    } else {
                        $(this).css("display", "table-row");
                    }
                });
            }
            $(document).ready(function() {
                clearEmptyRows();
            });
    </script>
```